# What is the difference between evict() and clear() methods in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-session

I want to *detach* object from *session* so I written code like is shown below. But it is not detaching from session, instead it is saving to the database.

How `evict()` and `clear()` methods work, can anybody answer please?

```
session.evict(student);
session.save(student);
```

Comment: You're calling `evict` then `save`? For why?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call `session.save(student);` and then `session.evict(student);` or `session.clear();` as it will not make sense vice versa. 
Answering your original question `session.evict(student);` will remove the object from the session while `session.clear();` will completely clear the session.

> clear() Completely clear the session.
>
> evict(Object object) 
>             Remove this instance from the session cache.

You could refer the official documentation at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html.
Hope that helps